# Assign keyboard shortcut to Visual Studio 2010 custom macro

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I had a macro (http://weblogs.asp.net/koenv/archive/2008/02/14/quick-attach-and-detach-debugger.aspx) in Visual Studio 2008 that attaches the debugger to IIS (for ASP.NET/WCF development). I assigned a shortcut to it using the options dialog.

Now I migrated the macro to Visual Studio 2010 but I can't find the macro in the list of commands to assign a shortcut to it, so apparently my macro is no longer recognized as a command. Strangely the out-of-the-box sample macro's in VS 2010 are in the list.

Anyone knows what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My problem when this happened is that the Module name has to match the name in the Macro Explorer.

ie:

```
Macros
    MyMacros
        Module1
            CollapseTree
```

has to have the code:

```
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub CollapseTree()
        'Code Here
    End Sub
End Module
```